# Angular - Открыть/закрыть sidenav из другого компонента

Tags: angular2

Всем привет и с наступающим Новым Годом.

Использую angular (последней версии) и angular material.

Есть 3 компонента:

- header.component, в котором находится кнопка управления правым sidenav'ом
- rigth-sidenav.component, в котором и находится тот самый sidenav
- sidenav.component (это левое основное меню), в этом компоненте вызывается header.component, right-sidenav.component и контент

С Ангуляром впервые столкнулся, подскажите, пожалуйста, как открыть/закрыть sidenav из другого компонента (в моем случае кнопка находится в header.component).

Пробовал следующий вариант (но получал ошибку: TypeError: this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav is undefined):

*header.component.html*

```html
<button mat-button (click)="toggleRightSidenav()">Согласование до 16:00 сегодня</button>
```

*header.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RightSidenavComponent } from '../right-sidenav/right-sidenav.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

 constructor(public RightSidenavComponent:RightSidenavComponent) { }
 toggleRightSidenav() {
  this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav.toggle();
 }
 
}
```

*sidenav.component.html*

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="sidenav"
     [fixedInViewport]="true"> Sidenav </mat-sidenav>
 <mat-sidenav-content>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-right-sidenav #rSidenav></app-right-sidenav>
 </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

*sidenav.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Directive, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RightSidenavComponent } from '../right-sidenav/right-sidenav.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})

export class SidenavComponent {
 
 @ViewChild('rSidenav') public rSidenav;
 constructor(public RightSidenavComponent: RightSidenavComponent) {
  this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav = this.rSidenav;
 }
 
}
```

*right-sidenav.component.html*

```html
<mat-sidenav #rightSidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="rightSidenav"
    [fixedInViewport]="true" [fixedTopGap]="250">
 Sidenav
</mat-sidenav>
```

*right-sidenav.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-right-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './right-sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./right-sidenav.component.scss']
})

@Injectable()
export class RightSidenavComponent {
 
 public rightSidenav: any;

 constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SidenavService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
    private sidenav: MatSidenav;


    public setSidenav(sidenav: MatSidenav) {
        this.sidenav = sidenav;
    }

    public open() {
        return this.sidenav.open();
    }


    public close() {
        return this.sidenav.close();
    }

    public toggle(): void {
    this.sidenav.toggle();
   }
```

Your Component

```
constructor(
private sidenav: SidenavService) { }

toggleRightSidenav() {
   this.sidenav.toggle();
}
```

App component.

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
}
```

App Module

```
providers: [YourServices , SidenavService],
```

Работающий пример: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tku8zp

Больше ответов и комментариев здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073057/angular-open-close-sidenav-from-another-component (аналогичный мой вопрос)